# Do I need to use userID to securely write to Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-security

I have the following Firestore security rule setup:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userID} {
        allow create;
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userID;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to save the users email, which they enter into a textfield in my SwiftUI app, and a random word generated by the app. Both are string values:

```
db.collection("wordOfDay").document(core.UID() ?? "").setData(["email": inputText, "word": Array(commonWords)[commonWordIndex].foreign ?? "", "date": todaysDate])
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the user's ID (core.UID() ?? "") that was generated and saved to UserDefaults when they first signed up, as the way of authenticating with Firestore rules.

However, the data never gets written.

When I let anyone access the database:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

It successfully writes.

I'm sure I have an authentication problem, as I have not found any way of sending Firestore the userID for the security rules.

Comment: That rule says that the user has to authenticated and the uids have to match, you have to make sure you use FirebaseAuth for that to work. Make you you are using the listener in the basic documentation to see if they are actially logged in instead of using some makeshift log in system. The documentation is pretty detailed.

Comment: @lorem ipsum I'm using FirebaseAuth. I don't think I'm using a makeshift log in system. I followed an article that used a proper email/password or Apple Sign In. Core.UID is being used so I can query Firestore to get an email address else where in my app. I thought I could use it when writing to Firestore so security rules can authenticate me.

Comment: using UserDefaults as your source of truth for log in info and log in state is makeshift. Firebase Auth provides a listener that handles all of that and provides the most current data on the subject. UserDefaults should also not be used to store sensitive information, you should use Keychain but that is not the issue here, your user is like "signed out" so the auth and the uid don't match

Answer (score 1):

The `allow read, write: if true;` in your last rules snippet means that anyone in the world can do whatever they want with each document, including deleting them. That's probably not what you want.

Your first set of rules only allow the user to access the document if their UID matches, which is a good example of implementing [owner-only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access). But your code doesn't match this requirement. Specifically the expression you call out:

```
core.UID() ?? ""
```

This says: if there is a `core` value (presumably a user) then use its UID, otherwise use an empty string. But an empty string is not a valid document ID in your code, and your rules won't allow it anyway.

Instead you should check if `core` has a value, and only access the database document for a user if there actually is a user signed in:

```
if (core != null && core.UID() != null) {
  db.collection("wordOfDay").document(core.UID()!).setData(...);
}
```